# Why does OCMock cause nsnotificaiton center to have EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using mockObserver

Tags: ocmock

I setup mock observers like this:

```
id quartileObserverMock = [OCMockObject observerMock];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addMockObserver:quartileObserverMock
                                                 name:kVPAdPlayerDidReachQuartileNotification
                                               object:self.adPlayer];

[[quartileObserverMock expect]
                       notificationWithName:kVPAdPlayerDidReachQuartileNotification
                                     object:self.adPlayer
                                   userInfo:@{@"quartile" : @(VPAdPlayerFirstQuartile), @"trackingEvent" : VPCreativeTrackingEventFirstQuartile}];
```

my unit tests run; but I get spurious EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors when the notificaiton is posted.

i.e.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                           postNotificationName:kVPAdPlayerDidReachQuartileNotification
                                         object:self.adPlayer
                                       userInfo:@{@"quartile" : @(quartile), @"trackingEvent" : trackingEvent}];
```

When I comment out the observermock code my tests run fine every single time.

When I put the code back in, I get spurious crashes on postNotiicaitonName:object:userInfo, maybe once every 2.5 times.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Your object parameter is self when you post the notification, but the observer is watching for a notification on self.adPlayer. Is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: yep - that's just a typo. I've updated it.

Answer (score 8):

Refer the following sample code, this might help you. It worked for me

```
- (void)test__postNotificationwithName__withUserInfo
{
     id observerMock  = [OCMockObject observerMock];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addMockObserver:observerMock name:@"NewNotification" object:nil];

     NSDictionary *userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2",@"2", nil];
     [[observerMock expect] notificationWithName:@"NewNotification" object:[OCMArg any] userInfo:userInfo];

     NotificationClass *sut = [[NotificationClass alloc] init];
     [sut postNotificationwithName:@"NewNotification" userInfo:userInfo];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observerMock];
     [observerMock verify];
}
```

and my posting notification method

```
- (void)postNotificationwithName:(NSString *)notifName userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notifName object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

**Please note:**

1. observerMock always raise an exception when an unexpected notification is received.
2. Remove the mocked observer from the NSNotificationCenter at the end of the test case.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons why this could be happening (I know, because I just solved both of them them in my own code today)

1) A mock observer from a previous test was not removed

2) An non-mock instance object from a previous test is observing for the same notification, but that object has since become obsolete. In my case, an instance object from my `setUp` method was listening to the notification, but when it was dealloced, it did not remove itself from the NSNotificationCenter's observers list.

In both cases the solution is to use

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:name:object:]
```

Depending on the scope: 1) in the `dealloc` of all classes that observe NSNotificationCenter, 2) in the `tearDown` method, or 3) at the end of the test case (as @PrasadDevadiga mentioned)